implementation 'com.github.mmin18:realtimeblurview:1.2.1' not supported provide some alternate or physical file to download
After clean the build and rebuild com.github.mmin18:realtimeblurview:1.2.1 the provided package is not available. Please resolve or provide a alternative solution.
